# Permission Denied (publickey) AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cygwin, public-key

I know this is one FAQ. But I am new to this. I went through all the given solution out there. But nothing seems to solve my problem

Following will explain you better.

```
ssh -v -i xxxxx-ec2.pem ubuntu@ec2-xx.xx.xx.xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I am getting

```
    OpenSSH_6.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/Administrator/.ssh/config
debug1: Connecting to ec2-xx-xxx-x-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [xx.xxx.x.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file xxxxx-ec2.pem type -1
debug1: identity file xxxxx-ec2.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA a6:6e:d1:d2:ec:73:f5:d7:5f:97:33:b7:6b:ef:ff:02
debug1: Host 'ec2-xx-xxx-x-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/Administrator/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: venkat-ec2.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

**Actually by mistake I deleted** the `xxxxx.pub` which was in the home/ubuntu folder when I was trying to rectify the above problem. But I generated a `.pub` file using

```
ssh-keygen -y
```

then just pasted the .pub file back into folder `/home/ubuntu/` via SFTP . Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the new content of the .pub in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys or /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys2.

Another way to do that is to use ssh-copy-id